# Generate "broken images" report using my browser (intranet)?

Tags: browser, images, report

I have an intranet site with many broken images.  I need to generate a report that shows which images the browser wasn't able to download during my browsing session (the report should span all of the pages browsed during the browsing session).

Is there something that will do this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Xenu's Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) may be what you are after.